# iOS Development: How can script the logic needed to determine if an Achievement has been earned?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm diving into iOS development and I'm playing around with the GameKit API and Achievements.  In my code, I basically have a function called checkAchievements() which has a bunch of "if" statements to determine if any achievements have been earned.  I'd like to put this logic in a script of sorts so I can hand it off to the game designers and let them add achievements and their conditions as they come up with them.  Basically, there are few things that are uglier than 100 lines of "if" statements and I'd love to get rid of them. Any suggestions?

Thanks so much in advance for all your wisdom!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the if statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the list of already-earned achievements with GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:. As an example, I call this loadAchievements method when my app starts, and store all the achievements in an NSMutableDictionary (achievementsDictionary). I also add newly-earned achievements to that dictionary while the app runs.

You can then do [classname hasAchievement:@"whatever"] to determine if the user already has any particular achievement.

```
-(void)loadAchievements {
    [achievementsDictionary removeAllObjects];  // clear the existing dict
    [GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *achievements, NSError *error) 
     {
         if(error == NULL) {
             for (int i=0; i < [achievements count]; i++) {
                 GKAchievement *achievement = (GKAchievement *)[achievements objectAtIndex:i];
                 [achievementsDictionary setObject:achievement forKey: achievement.identifier];
             }
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"achievementsLoaded" object:self userInfo:nil];
         }
     }];
} 

-(BOOL)hasAchievement:(NSString *)identifier {
    if ([achievementsDictionary objectForKey:identifier] != nil) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

See also: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKAchievement_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I apologize if my question was unclear, but I'm looking for a way to represent the conditions for earning an achievement in some way other than a bunch of if statements.

Comment: Ahh. Well, I think that depends on your particular project. Not sure I see any way around it though, except maybe by categorizing achievements and narrowing things down that way. (by score, level, etc.)